# Symfony 2 Logout, user still authenticated

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to implement `remember_me` in login, but I Have some trouble

My user is authenticated, but when i try to logout, the user still authenticated ( I can see in debug toolbar)

This is security.yml

```
 remember_me:
      key:      "%secret%"
      lifetime: 31536000 
      path:     /
      domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
```

I try even `invalidate_session: true` but I have the same problem.

My Route

```
login_check:
    path: /login_check

logout:
    path:   /logout
```

like documentation. I didn't create controller about logout.

My questions are:

1. How can I implement logout (if I don't add remember_me option, all
   works)
2. How Symfony know where redirect for my action Logout? I saw that use
   this Handler

   Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Logout/LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface.php

**Update**

If Implement `<a href="{{ url('logout') }}">Logout</a>` in my twig, it works. I write `logout` in my browser, dosen't work... it's so strange

Answer (score 0):

Your firewall configuration should look like this:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            logout: ~
```